# driver.find_elements() in Selenium returns different or no elements after click()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a list of companies from a fair website as they are not providing a .csv. The list seems to be based on ajax. On each page there is a number of companies listed out of which I extract the company name and the country. Iterating through those companies, I would like to click on the company name and be redirected to the company details page where I would pick up the email if given.

When I return back however, I get a 'StaleElementReferenceException'. To fix that, I recreate the page_list (list of WebObjects (companies)). But every time I repull that list, I get a different list of companies although the companies from every page do not change when manually browsing. Sometimes that list is even empty. And sometimes that list contains elements that have previously been parsed.

[My Code in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/lawanrahim/161cc8f38ee3bfc27456d11a184596d2)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @D.L - The code posted by OP is in the form of text only, not image.

Comment: @Shawn,  surely it makes sense for the code (question) and the answer to exist in the same place ?

Comment: I was referring to your first comment where you asked OP to post the code in the form of text and not image. Surely the code by OP is in text format only. About your second comment, having code in the same place, it really doesn't matter to me as long as I can copy the code quickly(from anywhere not necessarily from the question)and replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have done few changes to your code, for example, I removed the code where you were going back to previous page using `Javascript`, I handled exceptions in some places and applied `ExplicitWaits`. Refer the modified code below:

```
# Import necessary libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
import csv
import re

# Base URL
base_url = "https://www.anuga.com/anuga-exhibitors/list-of-exhibitors/"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Initialize the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

def extract_email():
    try:
        email_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'mailto:')]/span")
        email = email_element.text.strip()
    except:
        email = None

    return email


# Main scraping logic

with open("companies.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Company Name", "Country", "Email"])

    driver.get(base_url)
    sleep(1)
    driver.maximize_window()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    for i in range(1, 355):
        # Wait for the list of companies to load
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'col') and contains(@class, 'ergebnis') and .//a/strong]")))
        sleep(1)
        page_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                         "//div[contains(@class, 'col') and contains(@class, 'ergebnis') and .//a/strong]")

        for idx in range(len(page_list) - 1):
            if idx == 0:
                element = page_list[idx]

            company_name = element.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a/strong").text.strip()
            country = element.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//p[1]").text.strip()

            # Click on the company name to navigate to the details page
            link_element = element.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[starts-with(@href, '/exhibitor/')]")
            # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link_element)
            link_element.click()

            # Extract email from the details page
            email = extract_email()

            # Navigate back to the list page
            # driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
            try:
                wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='To the search overview']"))).click()
            except:
                driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
            # Re-acquire the list of company elements
            WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
                 (By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'col') and contains(@class, 'ergebnis') and .//a/strong]")))
            page_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                          "//div[contains(@class, 'col') and contains(@class, 'ergebnis') and .//a/strong]")
            # Also re-acquire the current company_element using the idx
            print(len(page_list))
            element = page_list[idx + 1]

            writer.writerow([company_name, country, email])
            print(f"""On page {i}/354. Added company {company_name}, country {country}, email {email}.""")

        # Move to the next page
        # try:
        next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@rel='next']")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
        sleep(1)
        print(f"""\nNow on page {i}. """)
        # except:
        # break  # No more pages to navigate

driver.quit()
```

**Result on console:** Obviously I did not wait until it scrapes all 354 pages.

```
C:\Users\anthony.dsouza\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\anthony.dsouza\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\test.py 
24
On page 1/354. Added company Buram GmbH, country Germany, email mustafa.sen@buram.de.
24
On page 1/354. Added company Frischpack Gruppe, country Germany, email info@frischpack-gruppe.de.
24
On page 1/354. Added company ICE-Agenzia per la Promozione All'Estero E L'Int.Ne delle Imprese Italiane, country Italy, email agroindustria@ice.it.
24
On page 1/354. Added company MOLINO RIVETTI PIETRO SRL IL PANE DI ANNA, country Italy, email ufficioestero@ilpanedianna.it.
24
On page 1/354. Added company Aden Kuru Gida Ith. Ihr. San. ve Tic. Ltd. Sti., country Türkiye, email bekir@adenfruit.com.
24
On page 1/354. Added company Adroit Overseas Enterprises Ltd, country Canada, email canada@adroitoverseas.com.
24
On page 1/354. Added company Africab, country Tanzania, email None.
24
On page 1/354. Added company AGARAS UAB, country Lithuania, email info@agaras.lt.
24
On page 1/354. Added company Agrícola Ferrari, country Brazil, email dalton.terc@agricolaferrari.com.br.
24
On page 1/354. Added company Agro Farovon Zamin LLC, country Uzbekistan, email agrofarovon@gmail.com.
24
On page 1/354. Added company AGROINDUSTRIA FRUTOS DE ORO SAC, country Peru, email None.
24
On page 1/354. Added company AGROMASS BRASIL IMPORTACAO EXPORTACAO, country Brazil, email roberta@agromassbrasil.com.br.
24
On page 1/354. Added company AKIB - Mediterranean Cereals, Pulses Oil Seeds & Products Exporters' Associat, country Türkiye, email tarim@akib.org.tr.
24
On page 1/354. Added company ALBACARA, country Italy, email INFO@ALBACARABIO.IT.
24
On page 1/354. Added company ALIBRA INGREDIENTES S.A, country Brazil, email marketing@alibra.com.br.
24
On page 1/354. Added company ANASSA ORGANICS, country Greece, email info@anassaorganics.com.
24
On page 1/354. Added company ANHUI GUJING DISTILLERY CO., LTD, country China, email zhangchenshuqiao@gujing.com.cn.
24
On page 1/354. Added company APIARIOS LAMBERHONEY, country Brazil, email samuels@samelhoney.com.br.
24
On page 1/354. Added company Aromatico Inversiones, country Peru, email clarissa@aromaticoperu.com.
24
On page 1/354. Added company ARROZEIRA PELOTAS IND. COM. CEREAIS LTDA, country Brazil, email comex01@arrozeirapelotas.com.br.
24
On page 1/354. Added company ASIAN FOOD SERVICE CO.,LTD., country Korea, Republic of, email spjeon@asianfoods.co.kr.
24
On page 1/354. Added company Az. Agr. Fisicaro Sebastiana, country Italy, email info@frantoiogalioto.it.
24
On page 1/354. Added company Baglio Bonsignore S.A. Srl, country Italy, email info@bagliobonsignore.it.

Now on page 1. 
20
On page 2/354. Added company Bem Brasil Alimentos S/A, country Brazil, email export@bembrasil.ind.br.
20
On page 2/354. Added company Bermak Tarim ve Sanayi Urunleri Insaat Ihracat Ithalat San. ve Tic. Ltd. Sti., country Türkiye, email bermak@bermak.com.tr.
20
On page 2/354. Added company BFT FOODS, country Brazil, email export@bftfoods.com.
20
On page 2/354. Added company BIO DISTRETTO BORGHI SICANI, country Italy, email biodistrettoborghisicani@gmail.com.
20
On page 2/354. Added company BIOSPICEFOODS EXPORTAÇÃO E IMPORTAÇÃO, country Brazil, email biospice@biospicefoods.com.br.
20
On page 2/354. Added company Bismi Cashew Company, country India, email info@bismicashewcompany.com.
20
On page 2/354. Added company Bodegas Cuvillier S.A, country Argentina, email hernancabrera@delvalle.com.ar.
20
On page 2/354. Added company Bom Principio Alimentos, country Brazil, email vinicius.correa@bomprincipioalimentos.com.br.
20
On page 2/354. Added company BRASECO COML IMP EXP REPR LTDA, country Brazil, email DAMARIS@BRASECOBRASIL.COM.BR.
20
On page 2/354. Added company BRMill Alimentos, country Brazil, email export@brmillalimentos.com.br.
20
On page 2/354. Added company BronteLab Srl, country Italy, email brontelabsrl@gmail.com.
20
On page 2/354. Added company CAIZFOR INTERNATIONAL BUSINESS, country Brazil, email b.macedo@caizfor.com.br.
20
On page 2/354. Added company Carmien Tea / Bergendal Rooibos, country South Africa, email charlrudman@carmientea.co.za.
20
On page 2/354. Added company CELENA ALIMENTOS, country Brazil, email execucaosp@celena.com.br.
20
On page 2/354. Added company CERERE SRL, country Italy, email info@cererefattoresiculo.com.
20
On page 2/354. Added company City Rice Import-Export Co. Ltd, country Cambodia, email raymond.ly@cityrice.com.
20
On page 2/354. Added company Claudia Luncke ProjektPartner für Events, country Germany, email events@luncke.com.
20
On page 2/354. Added company Colombian National Poultry Federation - FENAVI, country Colombia, email lralvarez@fenavi.org.
20
On page 2/354. Added company CONSORZIO MADE IN SICILY, country Italy, email consorzio.madeinsicily@gmail.com.

Now on page 2. 
20
On page 3/354. Added company COPA CAFE COMERCIO E EXPORTACAO LTDA, country Brazil, email info@coffeecopa.com.
20
On page 3/354. Added company Costa & Montenegro Industria, Comercio, Importacao e Export, country Brazil, email costaemontenegro@costaemontenegro.com.br.
20
On page 3/354. Added company Daivida, UAB, country Lithuania, email export@rokiskiomesine.lt.
20
On page 3/354. Added company deli carte GmbH & Co. KG, country Germany, email info@sauels.de.
20
On page 3/354. Added company Delta Foods Import & Export Solutions, country Brazil, email export@deltafoods.com.br.
20
On page 3/354. Added company DEMETRA SOCIETA' COOPERATIVA A MUTUALITA' PREVALENTE, country Italy, email commerciale.oliosaalgasicilia@gmail.com.
20
On page 3/354. Added company Dikoko, country Brazil, email export@malibru.com.br.
20
On page 3/354. Added company Doc's Ginger GmbH, country Germany, email info@docsginger.de.
20
On page 3/354. Added company efko cz s.r.o., country Czech Republic, email efko@efkocz.cz.
20
On page 3/354. Added company EL BOSQUE EMPRESA INDIVIDUAL DE R LTDA, country Peru, email info@elbosque.com.pe.
20
On page 3/354. Added company EMPRESA BRASILEIRA DE BEBBIDAS E ALIMENT, country Brazil, email jesse.carreno@britvic.com.
20
On page 3/354. Added company Farma Rudimov s.r.o. Maso z Luky, country Czech Republic, email karel@masozluky.cz.
20
On page 3/354. Added company FRASSON LORENZO, country Italy, email manufrasson@gmail.com.
20
On page 3/354. Added company FRIBIN SAT Nº 1269 RL, country Spain, email fribin@fribin.com.
20
On page 3/354. Added company Frooty Açaí, country Brazil, email export@frooty.com.br.
20
On page 3/354. Added company Funky ouma, country South Africa, email jo@funky-ouma.co.za.
20
On page 3/354. Added company Fysis- Corphes, country Greece, email info@corphes.gr.
20
On page 3/354. Added company G. D. Foods Mfg. (I) Pvt. Ltd., country India, email exports@tops.in.
20
On page 3/354. Added company GOLDEN SEEDS SRL, country Bolivia, email mghetti@gdseeds.com.

Now on page 3. 
20
On page 4/354. Added company Hattah (Shanghai) Supply Chain Management Co., Ltd., country China, email tongyongmin01@100.me.
20
On page 4/354. Added company HEFEI DIELEGANCE BIOTECHNOLOGY CO., LTD., country China, email simon@dielegancebiotech.com.
20
On page 4/354. Added company Heilongjiang Weiduobao Food Co., Ltd., country China, email 1253338780@qq.com.
20
On page 4/354. Added company HELLENIC FARMS S.A., country Greece, email info@hellenicfarms.gr.
20
On page 4/354. Added company HMF Food Production GmbH & Co. KG, country Germany, email kontakt@mds-holding.de.
20
On page 4/354. Added company Homemade, country Brazil, email lgulminelli@ecil-trading.com.br.
20
On page 4/354. Added company HRYSAFIS S.A., country Greece, email info@hrysafidairy.gr.
20
On page 4/354. Added company HUANGSHAN UNITED KEEMUN TEA CO., LTD, country China, email ymteanancy@gmail.com.
20
On page 4/354. Added company Hunan Xiangfeng Tea Industry Co., Ltd, country China, email j.liu@xf-tea.com.
20
On page 4/354. Added company Iconic Drinks GmbH (Blue Farm), country Germany, email max@bluefarm.co.
20
On page 4/354. Added company IGM Vietnam Company Limited, country Vietnam, email rd@igmvn.com.
20
On page 4/354. Added company Indagro for Food & Agricultural Industri, country Egypt, email sara.mohamed@indagroegypt.com.
20
On page 4/354. Added company Jain Farm Fresh Foods Limited, country United Kingdom, email peter.davis@jainfarmfresh.co.uk.
20
On page 4/354. Added company KAMPONG THOM RICE MILL LIMITED, country Cambodia, email sokhorng.lim@kampongthomrice.com.
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the website redirected the driver to the home page after a couple of clicks. Increasing the sleep time in between clicks significantly, helped overcome the issue.